# Affordable timelapse motion control

Tags: timelapse

I am looking for a timelapse motion control. So far, the cheapest I have found is the Genie, which is about $1000ish (with accessories). Is there a more affordable alternative?

Comment: What gear do you use? For Canon DSLRs there is the TC-80N3 (wired remote control) which can be "programmed" to perform timelapse shots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire point of the [Genie](http://www.genietimelapse.com/) is that it was to offer a *more affordable* option then the other products on the market. You are looking for something *even more* affordable. You are probably best off with a [DIY solution](https://www.google.com/search?q=diy%20time%20lapse%20rig&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS512US512&oq=diy%20time%20lapse%20rig&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i64.3130j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) that will of course be less flexible, more clunky, error prone, and ugly. But it could end up costing you less.

I have heard of one other competitor that is less expensive but I don't know much about the products: [SlideTracked](http://www.slidetracked.com/)

Comment: I like the idea of the genie, but its still rather expensive for what is essentially a motor and a timer in a box...